# How to download photos from telegram channel using Madeline?

Tags: php, telegram

I use MadelineProto
I need to get a photo from the last post in telegram
The code I use:

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->start();

$channel = '@example';
$offset_id = 0;
$limit = 1;

$messages_Messages = $MadelineProto->messages->getHistory(['peer' => $channel, 'offset_id' => $offset_id, 'offset_date' => 0, 'add_offset' => 0, 'limit' => $limit, 'max_id' => 0, 'min_id' => 0, 'hash' => 0 ]);

$message = $messages_Messages['messages'][0];
echo json_encode($message);

$MadelineProto->downloadToFile($message, "/tmp.png");
```

$message :

```
{"_":"messageMediaPhoto","photo":{"_":"photo","has_stickers":false,"id":5**54901******2695,"access_hash":-82*****8334,"file_reference":{"_":"bytes","bytes":"AkV4QiEAABFvYFze*****QoZFrTBH7fvQ="},"date":1616692497,"sizes":[{"_":"photoStrippedSize","type":"i","bytes":{"_":"bytes","bytes":"ASgdpA8dV\/EU0n*****FFJjTA=="}},{"_":"photoSize","type":"m","location":{"_":"fileLocationToBeDeprecated","volume_id":4****0743,"local_id":44***85},"w":231,"h":320,"size":12760},{"_":"photoSize","type":"x","location":{"_":"fileLocationToBeDeprecated","volume_id":4000****43,"local_id":44***6},"w":502,"h":696,"size":36269}],"dc_id":4}}
```

The data on the photo comes in, but the file is not created, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in the end Madeline is going a little crazy

You just had to add the **DIR** constant

Last line of code:

```
$MadelineProto->downloadToFile($message,  __DIR__ . "/tmp.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with the downlowntodir() method .(**no diffrences**)

```
try {
    if (isset($update['message']['media']))
    {

        $file = $this->download_to_dir($update, './downloads/');
    }
} catch (\danog\MadelineProto\PRCErrorException $e) {
    echo "Exception";
}
```

as you see , if you just add a dot followed by a slash '**./** ' the bot will download the file in the same directory where your '**bot.php**' is placed .(in my case it's downloaded to '**downloads**' dirctory which is at the same directory where '**bot.php**' is placed .

or you can

```
download_to_dir(); // is for madelineproto version 5.1.34
downloadToDir(); //is the updated one for version 6.x
```